# Why my simple Exec gradle task doesn't work and logs are not explicit?

Tags: gradle

I don't understand why this very simple task using gradle doesn't work ?

> task test(type:Exec) {
>        commandLine 'ls -l'    }

the output just tell me that :

> $ gradle  test    :test FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':test'.
>
>   > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ls -l''
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED code here

What is wrong with my use?

Comment: Does it work if you use executable+args instead of commandLine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
task test(type:Exec) { commandLine 'ls', '-l' }
```

BTW: you really should specify working directory too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Radim, it works. I will specify a working directory.  I still think that the log is not very clear. But maybe I have to get used a little more to gradle.